# Sql Select data pick id from string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**Category Table**

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | category_name         |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | Buy Book              |
|  2 | Buy other thinks      |
+----+-----------------------+
```

**Buy Table**

```
+----+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
| id | identity              | name     | description | per_rate | bought | costs |
+----+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  1 | PROJECT[1]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | PHP BOOK    | 10       | 50     | 5000  |
|  2 | PROJECT[1]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | PHP BOOK    | 10       | 40     | 4000  |
|  3 | PROJECT[2]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | JS BOOK     | 2        | 50     | 100   |
+----+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

I Want to Select category name from Other table when I select this table.

identity: PROJECT[**project_id**]CATEGORY[**category_id**]

So There are any way to pick the category id and select category name from other table

**I Want Like This Table**

```
+----+---------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
| id | category_name | identity              | name     | description | per_rate | bought | costs |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|  1 |  Buy Book     | PROJECT[1]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | PHP BOOK    | 10       | 50     | 5000  |
|  2 |  Buy Book     | PROJECT[1]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | PHP BOOK    | 10       | 40     | 4000  |
|  3 |  Buy Book     | PROJECT[2]CATEGORY[1] | BOOK     | JS BOOK     | 2        | 50     | 100   |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Do please show us what you have tried

Comment: I can't do anything for solve this.

Comment: Use SubString to get the key from the identity value, and then join across onto your category table.

Comment: Any demo or tutorial link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a really bad data structure.  The `project` and `category` should be in their own columns, with numbers stored properly as numbers, and proper foreign key relationships.  In MySQL, doing this might require a trigger, but it is worth it.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad decisions.  You can do what you want using `like`:

```
select b.*, c.category_name
from buy b join
     category c
     on b.identity like concat('%CATEGORY[', c.id, ']');
```

However, you should probably put effort into fixing the broken data structure.

Comment: It's working ... and (project and category should be in their own columns) it's a great Idea. **THANKS**